# Convert flat json to nested json using jolt transform

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

The input json :

```json
{
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2",
  "key3": "value3",
  "key4": "value4"
}
```

The expected output:

```json
{
  "key1" : "value1",
  "Name" : {
    "key2" : "value2",
    "key3" : "value3",
    "key4" : "value4"
  }
}
```

I would like to have a jolt transform, which can nest few fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a **shift** transformation with a conditional logic: picking **key1** and the rest of the attributes(**`"*"`**) such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "key1": "&",
      "*": "Name.&"
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/

[image]